# The Fokker-Planck Equation Derivation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I'm slightly confused by the sketch proof of the Fokker Planck equation given to me in my lecture notes. I was hoping someone might be able to spread some light on the issue I'm having. It essentially boils down to an integration by parts problem I think.

This is the form I'm trying to derive:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(u,t;u_0,0)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u(t))p(u,t;u_0,0)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}((G(u(t))^2p(u,t;u_0,0))
\end{equation}

**Sketch Proof**

Given any smooth function $\phi$ we examine $\mathbf{E}^{u_0}[\phi(u(t))]:=\mathbb{E}[\phi(u(t))|u(0)=u_0]$. Therefore

\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{E}^{u_0}[\phi(u(t))]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(u(t))p(u,t;u_0,0)du 
\end{equation}
Using the Ito formula and the fact that the expected value of Ito integrals are zero we have

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}^{u_0}[\phi(u(t))]=\mathbf{E}^{u_0}[\phi(u(s))]+\mathbf{E}^{u_0}\bigg[\int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\phi(u(s))f(u(s))+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}\phi(u(s))(G(u(s))^2dt\bigg]
\end{equation}
Differentiate with respect to $t$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{E}^{u_0}[\phi(u(t))]=\mathbf{E}^{u_0}\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\phi(u(t))f(u(t))+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}\phi(u(t))(G(u(t))^2\bigg]
\end{equation}
And by the definition of expectation above 
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(u(t))\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(u,t;u_0,0)du=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\bigg[\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial u}(u(t))f(u(t))+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}\phi(u(t))(G(u(t))^2\bigg]p(u,t;u_0,0)du
\end{equation}
If we make assumptions on $p\rightarrow0$ as $u\rightarrow\infty$ we can use integration by parts once on $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}fp$ and twice on $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial u^2}Gp$ to get 
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(u(t))\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(u,t;u_0,0)du=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(u)\bigg[-\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u(t))p(u,t;u_0,0)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}((G(u(t))^2p(u,t;u_0,0))\bigg]du
\end{equation}
Since this holds for all smooth $\phi$ we must have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(u,t;u_0,0)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u(t))p(u,t;u_0,0)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}((G(u(t))^2p(u,t;u_0,0))
\end{equation}
The part I am struggling with is the where I have to use integration by parts. For some reason I just don't see how to get the next equation. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Many thanks.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the details or with knowing why you're doing what you're doing?

Comment: A bit of both I would imagine. Mainly though, I can't how to get the second to last expression through integration by parts.

Comment: My idea is to use the fact that $\int_a^b g'(x)h(x)dx=-\int_a^b g(x)h'(x)$ when g'(a)=g'(b)=0 but no such luck

Comment: sorry i meant g(a)=g(b)=0

Comment: This is integration by parts on an infinite domain. If $g$ goes to zero at $\pm \infty$ and $f$ doesn't blow up at $\pm \infty$ then there is no boundary term in the integration by parts as well, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f g' = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty f' g$. Note that this does still require an additional assumption because there are integrable functions that don't go to zero at infinity.

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks. I've finally got it!